# Similar to battleships. How do i print descending order with a border like so?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I have a program that I created which is a game based upon floors and rooms in a building. The size of the rows and columns of the 2D array can change based upon user input. What I am trying to do is have a method that prints out the 2D array upon every guess the user enters, similar to playing Battleship.

Please notice in the image the bottom left corner would be [0][0], so the printing of the array needs to descend from top to bottom. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I already have a method that is filling out the array with blank spaces, and as user 1 or 2 guesses it fills in that element of the array with a '1' or a '2'.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

What I have tried so far (this is part of my toString method for printing. Must return a string.

```
public String toString() {
    String returnStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myHidingPlaces.length; ++i) {
        if (i == this.myHidingPlaces.length - 1) {
            returnStr += this.myHidingPlaces[i][0] + "\n ";
            for (int j = 0; j < this.myHidingPlaces[i].length; ++j) {
                returnStr += this.myHidingPlaces[i][j] + " ";
            }
        } 
        else {
            returnStr += this.myHidingPlaces[i][0];
        }
    }
    return returnStr;
}
```

Comment: Let's see what you've tried, a nice concise [mcve] if possible.

Comment: `String#format` comes to find, for [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format). Or `System.out.printf`

Comment: I edited it so show what I have tried. I took out the borders and what not because it was confusing. I wanted to get the output right before I added all the borders and seperators

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am not too worried about how to format the table as much as how to print it out in a descending order, with [0][0] being the bottom left corner.

Comment: So, start at the `.length - 1` position of the vertical group and work down to `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create a `char[][]` to store the board. The height of the board is 1 (the top line) + 2 * the amount of rows. The width of the board is 1 (this side line) + 4 * the amount of columns.

```
int boardHeight = 1 + 2*myHidingPlaces.length;
int boardWidth = 1 + 4*myHidingPlaces[0].length;
char[][] board = new char[boardHeight][boardWidth];
```

Lets start the board with a clean state; make every `char` the `' '` space character.

```
for(int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
        board[i][j] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Every second row is all `'_'` characters apart from the first and last character

```
for(int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i += 2) {
    for(int j = 1; j < boardWidth - 1; j++) {
        board[i][j] = '_';
    }
}
```

Every fourth column is all `'|'` characters apart from the first row

```
for(int i = 1; i < boardHeight; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j += 4) {
        board[i][j] = '|';
    }
}
```

Then you need to fill in all the elements in `myHidingPlaces` into the board. The translation from logical data to view data must be made. First flip the the row value (`y = height - y - 1`) and then scale the x and y components to sit in the middle of the squares:

```
for(int y = 0; y < myHidingPlaces.length; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < myHidingPlaces[0].length; x++) {
        if (myHidingPlaces[y][x] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        int i = myHidingPlaces.length - y - 1;
        i = 1 + 2*i;
        int j = 2 + 4*x;
        // translate int to char;
        char val = (char) (myHidingPlaces[y][x] + '0');
        board[i][j] = val;
    }
}
```

Finally print the board line-by-line onto the screen;

```
for(int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(board[i]));
}
```

---

sample board:

```
int[][] myHidingPlaces = new int[][] {
        {2,0,0},
        {0,0,0},
        {0,0,0},
        {0,0,1},
        {0,0,0},
};
```

Sample Output:

```
 ___________ 
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   | 1 |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
| 2 |   |   |
|___|___|___|
```

Comment: Is there a reason I am getting downvoted? This is like my 4th post on this website on constantly get downvoted. I feel like I act professional and try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @ThereIsNoSpoon posts are supposed to ask a single question and, where appropriate, a minimal code example stating exactly whats not working. This question is really asking a lot of things; ie fliping the coordinates could probably be a different question than how to create a boardered grid. Having questions that are too project sepcific really goes against the theme of the site. We want questions that are widely applicable so they can be useful to future users, not just the original question asker.

Comment: @ThereIsNoSpoon just keep asking questions. I dont agree with all the standards here and get hit with downvotes from time to time too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Run the height loop in the reverse order:

```
public String toString() {
    String returnStr = "";
    for (int i = this.myHidingPlaces.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.myHidingPlaces[i].length; j++) {
            returnStr += this.myHidingPlaces[i][j] + " ";
        }
        returnStr += "\n";
    }
    return returnStr;
}
```

Comment: Borders omitted since OP commented they are not the primary issue.